# The jacobian of a linear map is 0 if and only if it is not surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let  $A : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a  linear  map.   Prove  that $\det(AA^t) \geq 0$  with  equality  if and only if   $A$  is  not   surjective. I proved the first assertion. If the equality holds I noticed that $A^{t}$ is not injective. It is a useful remark?

Comment: This has many steps: showing that the det is never negative, that it is zero for non-surjective maps, and showing that with det = 0 the map can't be surjective. What's your "first assertion"?

Comment: @ The Vee I proved that $det(A\cdot A^{t})\geq 0$.

Comment: OK, I asked because it could have been understood you found one of the ⇒'s and were struggling with the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finishing the proof from where you got can be done like this:

1. If $\det(AA^T) \ne 0$ then $A$ is surjective:

If $AA^T$ is a regular matrix then it is invertible and for each $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ there is an $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ (namely $(AA^T)^{-1}y$) such that $y = AA^Tx$. Then we can see that for each $y$ there is a $z$ such that $y = Az$ (which is the definition of surjectivity): find the corresponding $x$ and take $z = A^Tx$.

2. If $\det(AA^T) = 0$ then $A$ is not surjective:

You have correctly shown that $A^T$ is not injective, that is actually **an important step**. If we know that two different $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ exist such that $A^T a = A^T b$, take a transposition of this result:

$$(a^T - b^T) A = 0.$$

This means

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n: (a^T - b^T) A x = 0.$$

Because $a^T - b^T \ne \vec 0$, $(a^T - b^T)(a - b) > 0$. So the above equality shows that $a-b$ can never be the result of $A x$ for any $x$, and that's a contradiction to surjectivity.